# Trigger JavaScript action after Datatable is loaded

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

In a `JSF 2.1` + `PrimeFaces 3.2` web application, I need to trigger a JavaScript function after a `p:dataTable` is loaded. I know that there is no such event in this component, so I have to find a workaround.

In order to better understand the scenario, on page load the dataTable is not rendered. It is rendered after a successful login:

```
<p:commandButton value="Login" update=":aComponentHoldingMyDataTable" 
                                    action="#{loginBean.login}" 
                                    oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args)"/>
```

As you can see from the above code, I have a JavaScript hook after the successful login, if it can be of any help. The `update` attribute forces the dataTable's rendered attribute to revaluate:

```
<p:dataTable  var="person" value="#{myBean.lazyModel}" rendered="#{p:userPrincipal() != null}" />
```

After the datatable is loaded, I need to run a JavaScript function on each row item, in order to subscribe to a [cometD](http://cometd.org/) topic.

In theory I could use the `oncomplete` attribute of the login Button for triggering a property from `myBean` in order to retrieve once again the values to be displayed in the dataTable, but it doesn't seem very elegant.

The JavaScript function should do something with the `rowKey` of each row of the dataTable:

```
function javaScriptFunctionToBeTriggered(rowKey) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Can you maybe explain what you are trying to accomplish from the description of a user story?  I am having trouble understanding what you want to accomplish because maybe there is a much simpler and more elegant way for you to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: @maple_shaft I have tried to be as clear as possible, and I dedicated some time in posting my question. Please let me know what is unclear so that I can improve it.

Comment: "Immediately after the `oncomplete` action has finished, the update attribute renders the dataTable". This part is not clear. `oncomplete` is client side action and comes *after* the ajax update.

Comment: Thanks @MattHandy , I have reformulated the point. If I understand your suggestion, I could use handleLoginRequest for reading the table's rowkeys.

Comment: Yes I am wondering why oncomplete is not sufficient for you. Do you want to make another ajax call from your javascript function?

Comment: I was not aware that oncomplete is fired after the datatable is loaded. I'll try later, but I am confident that this will solve my problem. No need to make other ajax calls. Thanks!

Comment: @MattHandy you were right, oncomplete is fired after the datatable is loaded, and the problem is solved. Will you post an answer, or shall I do it? Or shall I delete the question?

Comment: I will post an answer. Good to hear that it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javascript method from the `oncomplete` attribute is called *after* the ajax request has finished and thus *after*  the dataTable is loaded.

So you can do the following:

```
<p:commandButton ... oncomplete="doSomething()"/>
```

and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

if the page reload, try to call in the document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    doSomething();
});
```